# error " object of type 'type' has no len() "

Tags: python, typeerror

```
vowlist=['a','e','i','o','u']
def piglatin(s):
    if len(s)==1:
        if s[0] in vowlist:
            return s[0]+'way'
        else:
            return s[0]+'ay'
    elif s[0]==' '*len(s):
        return ' '
    elif len(s)>1:
        if s[0] in vowlist or (s[0]=='y' and s[1] not in vowlist):
            return s[0:]+'way'
        else:
            return new(s)
def new(s):
    global str
    if s[0] not in vowlist:
        str=s[0]+new(s[1:])
    else:
        return s[len(str):]+str[0:]+'ay'
print piglatin('school')
print piglatin('yttribium')
print piglatin('yolo')
```

This is the code I've written. It is supposed to output:

```
oolschay
yttribiumway
oloyay
```

But it gives the error `object of type 'type' has no len()` Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please post your code into the question directly (you can format with CMD-K) , rather than on a third party site like `CoderPad`. You should also tag it with the programming language (Python in this case). I've edited your question to fix it, but it will make you much more likely to get an answer in the future

Comment: You need to define a __len__ function.
Refer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089682/python-typeerror-object-of-type-has-no-len

Comment: In the future, give the full debug message (eg. what line the error occurred on).

Answer (score 5):

`str` is a type in Python. Use a different identifier for your variable. Change this method:

```
def new(s):
    global str
    if s[0] not in vowlist:
        str=s[0]+new(s[1:])
    else:
        return s[len(str):]+str[0:]+'ay'
```

to this:

```
def new(s):
    global my_str
    if s[0] not in vowlist:
        my_str=s[0]+new(s[1:])
    else:
        return s[len(my_str):]+my_str[0:]+'ay'
```

Comment: This won't work, as `my_str` is not defined if the code goes into the `else` branch

Comment: @DavidRobinson Isn't `my_str` is a global? I don't really know what the full context of the code is or where `new` is being used, but I know why the OP's problem is occurring.

Comment: I think the OP was confused in having the `global str`.